# PHP Help, if else

Tags: php

Well I have this check install index page that displays a login form if a certain file exists, and the login form doesn't display, just the install page.. I have no idea why because if you click install it won't let you because the files exist?

```
<?php
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 4096);
ob_implicit_flush(true);

//Load & Auth Setup
$int = '/core/config/int.php';
if (file_exists($int)) {
echo'
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    #wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    }
    </style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>';
 } else { 
 echo'
 <head>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Install</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    #wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    }
    </style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h2>
<small>
Not complete
</small>
</h2>
<p>
<p>
<p>Get setup in minutes! Enjoy the super easy installation wizard to walk you through the setup process.</p>
<p>Start your installation by clicking the button below!</p>
</p>
<p>
<a href="install/">
Install
</a>
</p>';
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Why is my index displaying the install html if the file exists?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Have you verified that the file exists, and exists at the exact location you are testing?  It's probably the path to the file that's causing you problems if you verified the file is where you expect it to be.

Comment: No that is what is weird, its infidelity there!

Comment: http://puu.sh/6JY7F.png

Comment: Change from relative to absolute path and see what happens.

Comment: Wait, what? is that how you have it right now? Like this? `/core/config/int.php` ?

Comment: The path you are now showing (`/core/config/int.php`) is probably not the absolute path. If you don't know the complete absolute path, try creating another php file in the same folder.  In that php file, echo `__FILE__` which will show you the absolute path and filename.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out!

`file_exists` function works in the OS scope, not http scope. So if you pass `/int` it will actually search for a folder named `int` in the root of your OS machine, not your webserver.

Use this:

`$int = __DIR__ . '/core/config/int.php';`

[`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) outputs the current directory, and I suppose that concatenating with `/core/config/int.php` it will locate it. Use it if you have PHP 5.3. or more.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have some weird permission issue on the web server, when you check file_exists on the file.

it's better to use absolute path rather then relative for this and enable error_reporting and display_errors that way you can get to the root of the problem far quicker.

Comment: I have two index pages ones within /install/ I copied the wrong one... Still isn't working :(